# Pretty print with incremental xml generation in lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml, increment, pretty-print

I am trying to write an xml file incrementally using [lxml](http://lxml.de). The incremental generation is explained [here](http://lxml.de/api.html#incremental-xml-generation).

In contrast to the "[conventional](http://lxml.de/api.html#serialisation)" xml generation I do not see a way to pretty print the resulting xml using the incremental generation.

Is there a way to use lxml and pretty print the resulting xml using the incremental method?